# Is it possible to access the symbol table in a macro?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-2.10, scala-macros

For example, to get all values, and their types, accessible at the macro's call site?
Or at least just the values from the current class? E.g.:

```
class A {
  val v1 = 10
  var v2 = "2"

  def m {
    val m3 = true

    // Here I would like to get information that v1: Int, v2: String and
    // v3: Boolean are available
    macroInvocation() 
  }
}
```

I looked in the Context and Universe, but couldn't find good methods.

Only solution I found so far is to get the macro's enclosing class/method (via the Context), and search the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Only solution I found so far is to get the macro's enclosing class/method (via the Context), and search the tree

I have the feeling that you mean that you are actually inspecting the AST itself in order to extract the declared fields. You don't have to do that.
If `c` is your `Context` value, you can just do:

```
c.enclosingClass.symbol.typeSignature.members
```

Comment: Well, yes, but then I have to inspect the method's declared values and variables, the class's fields, the class may be nested, then the class may inherit some fields from other classes/traits etc. All in all, quite a lot of places to look in. I wondered if the information is maybe already available (the compiler must have it somewhere, question is, is it public).

Comment: I don't have enough experience with macros to give a definite answer, but I'd say that you won't find anything better (other than maybe borrow some helpers in other macros you could find on github by example). I don't think you can access the symbol table. For one thing, the symbol table is mutable and will certainly not be accessible as is. It would at the very least need to be exposed as a limited read-noly version (such as `SymbolTableApi` for consistency with the rest of the reflection/macro api). But it does not seem like such a class/trait exists.

Comment: A minor nitpick: I don't think "symbol table" is the word we're looking for here. Perhaps "scope" would work better? @adamw wants to be able to see whatever is in scope where his macro is running. Symbol table is (in my experience, anyway) more of a static flat list of symbols, which tend to be mangled names (and in the JVM's case, a forgetful mangling that loses type information) for external consumption. Perhaps Scala does things differently though.

Comment: It seems that you are talking about the symbol table in .class files, while I (and probably adamw too) am talking about the compiler's symbol table. Specifically: http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/symtab/SymbolTable.html

Comment: Yes, @MyseriousDan is correct, I'm loooking for information on what's in the current scope where the macro was invoked. Sorry if I messed up the terminology. I suppose there's some "map"/"table" that the compiler uses to resolve references, not sure how it is exactly called in the Scala compiler.

Comment: Ahem, as I said in my above comment, yes there is, and it is precisely called SymbolTable (granted, this might contain more than just what is currently in scope, but in any case it is not in a "mangled" format). It's internal to the compiler though. @Myserious Dan: where you talking specifically about reflect.internal.SymbolTable.Scope ? Or did you use "Scope" as a general concept?

Comment: Just as a general concept, so I guess Scala's internals actually do use the term symbol table the way you guys are using it. I hadn't come across that usage (as being anything but what I described earlier) before, and have usually just heard it called a scope or context (often represented as a capital gamma symbol in PL circles). Either way, not much point on being a stickler for terminology if it doesn't match actual usage :) Sorry for the diversion!